# manipulating dom by native methods

Tags: javascript, dom

i would like to do something without using any libraries jquery, or zepto, i was used to them so now i have a little difficulties to realisez my goalI have this :

```
<div id="container">
    <div>blablabla....</div>
    <div>blablabla....</div>                     
</div>
```

And i would like to remove the first child, i have tried a lot of thinsgs, and after some search i know that solution may looks like this:

```
document.getElementById("container").removeFirstChild()
```

or

```
.removeChild(document.getElementById("container").firstChild)
```

but i cannot get the right solution, i always get errors exception or not the result wished.
So thanks in advance for your help, by the way this is my first intervention on this forum, may be not the last :-)

Comment: For academic purposes, right? Academic purposes are good purposes :-)

Comment: Why are you so determined to write this code instead of using a library ?

Comment: The first child or the first child element?

Comment: Are you really doing nothing`.removeChild()`? In JS `a.b` is a reference to the property/function/method `b` on object the `a`; you always have to specify the object to look for the property in.

Answer (score 4):

You could do as follows:

```
document.getElementById("container").removeChild( 
   document.getElementById("container").firstChild 
);
```

**UPDATE:**
As Juan Mendes points out, you can save one `getElementByID()` call by saving in a variable, like this:

```
container = document.getElementById("container");
container.removeChild( container.firstChild );
```

Comment: I would avoid multiple calls to `document.getElementById("container")`,

Comment: @JuanMendes for readability? I guess `getElementById` is pretty fast.

Comment: Yes `getElementById` is pretty fast, but I think it's more readable that way too.

Comment: thanks for your advices, but none of the methods are working, or may be i m not using them correctly, but when i apply this on my code, when i inspect my html dom with web inspector, all nodes are still there,

Comment: Even without performance benefits, it looks more kosher to me

Comment: @bossy It's probably just deleting a whitespace text node.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elm=document.getElementById('container');
var chl=elm.firstChild;
while(chl)
{
    if(chl.nodeType==1)
    {
        elm.removeChild(chl);
        break;
    }
    chl=chl.nextSibling;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DrJYM/)

Comment: Error free and for cross-browser issues :)